# Is there a free online computer calculator that is more powerful than wolframalpha.com?

Tags: algorithms

I need a calculator that accepts inputs using product notation, can compute the following, and can return the result in scientific notation:

$$\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^{3.1536\times10^{16}}(52!-i)}{52!^{3.1536\times10^{16}}}$$

I have tried wolframalpha.com, desmos.com, and Excel. None of them can do the calculation. Is there another calculator that would work?

Answer (score 2):

There are absolutely huge numbers involved in this calculation, no wonder you won't get the result by simple numerical computation.

However,

Let $x = 52!$ and $y=3.1536\times 10^{16}$.

A crude lower bound yields:
$$ \frac{\prod_{i=1}^y(x-i)}{x^y} \geq (1 - \frac{y}{x})^y \geq 1-\frac{y^2}{x} .$$
Putting numerical values and wandering on the safe side of approximations you get:
$$1-\frac{y^2}{X} \geq 1-10^{-34}$$.

Thus,

$$ 1-10^{-34} \leq \frac{\prod_{i=1}^y(x-i)}{x^y} \leq 1 $$.

The value you are looking for is basically $1$.